# Uncapacited Facility Location optimized brute force

Tags: optimization, graph, brute-force

How can I optimize a brute force method to find optimal solution for UFL problem? My solution is working very slowly.

If you already know the UFL problem, you can just jump the following description.

> There is a graph ***G***. We can divide ***G***'s vertices in 2 subsets ***C*** and ***F***.
>
> ***C*** is the subset of clients and ***F*** the subset of facilities.
>
> Every client has a distance to every facility, that is, ***dij*** is the distance from client ***i*** to facility ***j***.
>
> Every facility ***i*** has a cost ***fi*** to open
>
> Every client ***i*** needs ***ci*** objects (from some facility)
>
> Every client ***i*** must be served by only one facility ***j***, at the price of ***(dij*** * ***ci)***
>
> We want to minimize the overall cost (to serve all clients and open the necessary facilities)

My solution is as simple as possible: test all possibilities of associating clients and facilities, and this is very bad, given that, for example, if I had 10 clients and 5 facilities, there would be 5^10 possibilities.

How can I optimize this? I thought about some preprocessings but I got confused with it because of the ***fi*** and I still didn't come up with anything.